# how to assign the javascript variable value to textbox - in PHP

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to display some javascript variable on my html page.

```
var resultDis = 10;
document.getElementById("totalAmount").value= resultDis;
```

using

```
<input type="number" id="totalAmount" name="totalAmount" 
class="form-control" ng-model="form.totalAmount" 
placeholder="Total Amount" value="">
```

Here 
totalAmount : id of text those i want assign the value

But on the form submission, null value goes of that textbox.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how and what to ask. HINT: Post a [mcve] so we can see your HTML. For example use the `<>` button in the editor. We cannot see if your inpute field has a name

Comment: When are you assigning var resultDis = 10; ? Some event? Is it possible you have not assigned the value before form submission? Or maybe the problem is in the php code? Because what you posted in your question is working.

Answer (score 0):

add `id="totalAmount"` to your text box.

```
<input id="totalAmount" ...>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have in your input `ng-model="form.totalAmount"` you can update the value with AngularJS:

```js
angular
  .module('MyApp', [])
  .controller('MyController', function($scope) {
    var resultDis = 10;
  
    $scope.form = {};
  
    // value assignment to form.totalAmount model
    $scope.form.totalAmount = resultDis;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
  <input 
         type="number" 
         id="totalAmount" 
         name="totalAmount" 
         class="form-control" 
         ng-model="form.totalAmount" 
         placeholder="Total Amount" 
         value="">
</div>
```

**Note** that now the input will show the variable `resultDis` value on the view.. But, how are you handling the form submit? Can you update your question with more code?

Comment: thanks sir,its work but when i submit the form then these textbox value goes to null

Comment: See and answer my comment on your question @PrashantKumbhar - for example you may need a `name="totalAmount"`

Comment: Than it should be something else in your code.. You have to make a deep review and show us more code in order to help you..

Comment: <input type="number" id="totalAmount" name="totalAmount" class="form-control" ng-model="form.totalAmount" placeholder="Total Amount" value="">

Comment: I updated your question. Please do that yourself from now on. How are you submitting? Ajax or normal form submit? Please update your question with your form and the form handling on the server

Comment: sounds good javascript value variable shows in the text box like you but actually now  submit in the database

Answer (score 0):

if you work in Visual Studio, you have to use ClientID:

```
var resultDis = 10; document.getElementById("<%=totalAmount.ClientID%>").value= resultDis;
```

Comment: not on Visual Studio works with PHP framework LARAVEL

Comment: please check document.getElementById("totalAmount").value in your browser console, after assigning resultDis value. if result is same as resultDis value, This will mean that maybe your javascript code has not any problem and your question is related to PHP.

Comment: it could be sir but when i enter the value manually other wise edit the value those are display from the javascript then it will works 100% perfect but not works without edit value

Comment: where is placed your javascript code. you have to place it on document ready($.ready(function(){ })) or event.